# strcmp argument type error

Tags: c

I am trying not to use `isSpace` function so the only thing came to mind is `strcpy` but I am getting an error

```
while ( walker > 0 &&   strcmp(a[walker - 1],space_const) )

Warning 86: argument 1 conflicts with formal definition
```

Anyone know how to fix this issue? `space_const` is a `char` initialized as `" "`

```
char* strTrim(char* string)
{
 char* a= string;

 char delims[3];
 char space_const[] =" ";
 char syntax_const[]=" \t\n\v";
 size_t walker = strlen ( a );
 strcpy(delims,space_const);
 /* Trim trailing spaces */
 while ( walker > 0 &&   strcmp(a[walker - 1],space_const) )
   --walker; 

 a[walker] = '\0';

 /* Trim leading spaces */
 walker = strspn ( a,syntax_const);
 memmove ( a, a + walker, strlen ( a + walker ) + 1 );
 return extractCmd(a ,space_const );
}
```

Comment: Is there a purpose to what you are doing? Because it seems to be a very round-about inefficient method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to compare a character (small integer) and a string.

```
char* a= string;
/*... */

strcmp(a[walker - 1], space_const);
         ^ character
```

`strcmp` looks like this

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
                  ^ string        ^ string
```

It's likely you want something like:

```
(a[walker - 1] == ' ' || a[walker - 1] == '\t' || ..)
```

You should write a function. but then you would end up **rewriting `isspace`**.

#### Why can't you use `isspace` in the first place ?

Answer (score 1):

By adding brackets after the variable a[], you have made it a char.  You must then dereference it back into a pointer using the ampersand &;  Such as:

```
while ( walker > 0 &&   strnicmp(&a[walker - 1],space_const, strlen(space_const)) )
```

Be very careful here, it looks like this could be used for a buffer overflow since the passed in string is not being validated.